# How to load dependency in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am a newbie with Meteor. 
I used Iron-Router and Blaze for my project (without React or React-Router) and I have some trouble to load dependency modules (now all files are loaded in the first time running of application).
Can anybody help me with the solution to this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Don't know what you are talking about. Which package do you want to use? If it's only iron router, meteor add iron:router and it's done. Where is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

it may help to post the folder structure of your project. 
Also run a `meteor list` and post the results. that will help us determine if some dependencies are conflicting.

Also, in meteor all of the detected `*.js` files will be included in the project. to exclude them, place in a folder outside of the directory where the `.meteor` folder is located.